# Is there a functional equation for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \exp \left(-n^{2} \pi x\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It is known that
$$
\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \exp \left(-n^{2} \pi x\right)
$$

has the funcyional equation
$$
\frac{1+2 \psi(x)}{1+2 \psi(1 / x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

how about
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\exp \left(-n^{2} \pi x\right)
$$
does this function has a functional equation of its own?

Thanks.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is your second sum, then $f(x)=-\psi(x+i).$

Comment: There are a lot of different relations between sums of this form, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function